# Show that $H \triangleleft G $ if and only if for every $x,y \in G $, $xy \in H $

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Edit: This edit is in view of the comments.

> Let $G $ be a group and $H \leq G $. Show that $H \triangleleft G $ if and only if for every $x,y \in G $, $xy \in H $ if and only if $yx \in H $.

Together with the edit, the question is now a new one. How should that proposition be interpreted?

Old question:

So this is excercise 2.33 of Rotman's introduction to theory of groups. I wasn't able to show that $H \triangleleft G $ implies $xy \in H $ for every $x,y \in G $. So I left it for later on and continued with the excercises and got to one that asks you to show that $SL (n,k) \triangleleft GL (n,k) $ for every $n\geq 1$, for every field $k $. So I thought of using the proposition I wasn't able to prove, and got to the following contradiction:

Take $A =  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$, $B=Id $ then $A,B \in GL (2, \Bbb {R})$ but $AB = A \notin SL (2, \Bbb {R}) $. Which would imply that $SL (2, \Bbb {R}) $ is not normal. However, i was able to prove easily that in fact $SL (n,k) \triangleleft GL (n,k) $ By showhing that $g SL (n,k) g^{-1} = SL (n,k)$ for every $g \in GL (n,k) $. Is anyone able to explain were is my error in the other method?

Comment: Exercise 2.33 as you have quoted it is obviously wrong. Please check that you have transcribed it correctly.

Comment: I had not transcribed it completely. Here it goes (it still looks ambiguous to me): If $H\leq G $, then $H \triangleleft G $ if and only if, for all $x,y \in G $, $xy \in H $ if and only if $yx \in H $. The commas are exactly the ones I wrote.

Comment: I modify the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise says that ($H \lhd G$) $\Leftrightarrow$ ($\forall x,y \in G$, $xy \in H \Leftrightarrow yx \in H$).

$(\Rightarrow)$ we have $H \lhd G$. Then, for all $b\in H, a \in G$, $aba^{-1} \in H$. Now, taking $x,y \in G$ such that $xy\in H$, then $x^{-1}(xy)x \in H$, or $yx \in H$. Similarly, we have $yx \in H$, then $xy\in H$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Taking $y\in H$ and $x\in G$, we prove that $xyx^{-1} \in H$. Indeed, we have $ey = y \in H$, or $(x^{-1}x)y \in H$, then $x^{-1}(xy)\in H$, so $xyx^{-1} \in H$. You get the conclusion.

EDIT: for the second question, you only prove that for all $A, B \in GL(n,k)$, then $AB \in SL(n,k)$ if and only if $BA \in SL(n,k)$. It is not difficult, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since $xy=y^{-1}(yx)y$, for any $x,y\in G$, if $yx\in H$, then $xy\in H$. Converse holds as well.

In your case, $AB\notin SL (2, \Bbb {R})$ won't mean that $SL (2, \Bbb {R})$ is not normal. It is like in logic premise being wrong will not affect the entire theorem.